# While uploading pdf showing error in ajax call error 403 forbidden a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page

Tags: javascript, ajax, padding, http-status-code-403

facing some problem While uploading pdf showing error in ajax call error 403 forbidden a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page
here is my ajax call >> upload pdf ajax call please resolve this

```
function submitIndividualSharedFileInviteCandidate() {
                var data = new FormData();
                var files = $('#individual')[0].files
                data.append('file',files[0]);
                if (!validateIndividualResumeUpload()) {
                    return false;
                }else{     
                    if(dummyData == "DummyData"){
                        currentactivity_dummyData = "btn_shareEmployee_uploadIndResume";
                        deleteDummyData();
                        removeDummyData="removeDummyData";
                        }
                  }     
    
    
                // var data = new FormData(formdata);
                var csrf = $("input[name='_csrf']").attr("value")
    
                $.ajax({
                    headers : {
                        "X-CSRF-TOKEN" : csrf
                    },
                    type : 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData : false, // Important!
                    contentType: false,
                    cache : false, //this is my servlet
                    data : data,
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "./parseResume",
    
                    success : function(result) {
                        if (result.status == "Done") {
                            current_employee_id = result.data.employeeId;
                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            $('#candidatesBlock1').empty();
    
                            
                        }
                        $(".tab-slider--navresumedetails li:nth-child(2)").trigger('click')
                        $(".tab-slider--navresumedetails li:nth-child(1)").css('pointer-events', 'none');
                        $(".add_candidate_form_parent").css('height', '698px');
                        $(".add_candidate_form_parent").css('overflow', 'auto');
                        
                        getSupplierEmail()
                        
                        var obj = result.data;
                        unparsed_resumes_list = obj;
                        current_employee_id = obj.employeeId;
                        $('#userId_unparesedResume').val(obj.employeeId);
                        unparsedBulkSharedResumePreview(obj);
                        $('#btn_save_unparsedSharedBulkResumes').html('Save');
    
                        
                        if (result.status == "error") {
                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
                }
```

while uploading pdf showing this error
403 Forbidden a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page